# Zend Framework, echo message if (!$row) not working

Tags: zend-framework

This should be straight forward if the row count is 0 I want to echo a message. Here is what I have:

```
public function getClubComment($id) {
$id = (int) $id;
$row = $this->fetchRow('club_id = ' . $id);
if (!$row) {
    echo 'No comments';
    }
    return $row->toArray();
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: `fetchRow` should return null if there are no results, what does `var_dump($row)` show?  On a side note, echo'ing from a DbTable/data mapper is not a good idea.  Return the null result to the application to decide what to do.

Comment: var_dump($row); shows nothing.. and ok thanks

Comment: At the very least, it should output `NULL` - var_dump will never produce no output.  Is your whole page blank?  Check the server error_log file for possible explanations.

Comment: if I add it in the model I get nothing, if I add it in the view I get the following error -> http://pastebin.com/BHLWbsdd

Comment: That would make sense since `$row` only exists within the function `getClubComment()`.  I guess you could try `var_dump($row); exit;` from `getClubComment()` in case the var_dump is getting hidden in your layout somewhere.

Comment: I have done and nothing is returned..

Comment: That's strange.  If nothing is showing, then I would think `if(!$row)` would evaluate to true.  But I guess it also explains why you weren't seeing the output.  Something doesn't seem right about how things are working.

Comment: Try using `if (empty($row))`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try something like:

```
//not sure if this will work as I don't do this kind of request anymore
public function getClubComment($id) {
$id = (int) $id;
$row = $this->fetchRow('club_id = ?',  $id);
if (!$row) {echo 'No comments';}
    return $row->toArray();
    var_dump($row);
}
```

I think you'll be happier doing something like this, takes most of the guess work out.

```
public function getClubComment($id) {
$id = (int) $id;
//create instance of Zend_Db_Select object
$select = $this select();
$select->where('club_id = ?', $id);
//fetchRow using Zend_Db_Select object
$row = $this->fetchRow($select);
//fetchRow() returns NULL so may as well test for that.
if ($row === NULL) {
    throw new Zend_Db_Table_Exception();
    }
    return $row->toArray();
    var_dump($row);
}
```

[Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) is really useful to use in the models as it normally takes care of properly quoting values and it very easy to build a fairly complex sql query with any sql. In this example I used discrete lines for each part of the select() but I could as easily have strung them all together. I personally like each line separate so I can change or troubleshoot easily.

Comment: The first code segment you gave doesn't work, and neither does the second I get this error -> http://pastebin.com/MR5r5L94

Comment: you have something else wrong then, somewhere else. What is on line 20?

Answer (score 0):

fetchRow returns an object, even if there is no results, that is why the condition in the if statement is always false, try this

```
if (!count($row))
```